# Keyboard navigation between classes

Tags: jquery, navigation, keyboard

I need some help please :'(

I try to add a keyboard navigation on my page between each `<article class="layout"></article>` tags.

Press "up" and "down" on your keyboard to see the code in action :
http://jsfiddle.net/5LJRh/2/

I try to operate this code on my page, but without success, any idea on what's wrong please ?
http://jsfiddle.net/LPvS9/2/

```
function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
        positions = [],
        here = $(window).scrollTop(),
        collection = $('.layout'); // ANYTHING WITH A CLASS OF layout ( class ="layout" ) becomes a 'stop point' for your navigation.

    collection.each(function () {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'], 10));
    });

    for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) {
            scroll = collection.get(i);
            break;
        }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) {
            scroll = collection.get(i - 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 700
        });
    }

    return false;
}


$(function () {
    $("#next,#prev").click(function () {
        return scroll($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});


$(window).keydown(function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38: // key is up
            scroll('prev');
            break;
        case 40: // key is down
            scroll('next');
            break;
        }
});
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Ok but this depends of the structure of my page. I update my post.

Comment: And the relevant markup. Again: Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple example to give you an idea.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/5T4ma/12/)
I have deleted some of your external resources that maybe were in conflict
and I added a script to move the sections

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var  positions = []
  $('#content article').each(function(){
       positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset().top));
    })
    console.log(positions)
    var count=-1
    var x=positions.length-1    
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            if(count>=x*(-1)&&count!==0){   
                count--
                console.log(count)
                $('body,html').stop().animate({ scrollTop:positions[count]},2000 )
                }else{event.preventDefault()}

            break;

        case 40:
            if(count<=x){
                count++
                console.log(count)
                $('body,html').stop().animate({ scrollTop:positions[count]},2000 )
                }else{event.preventDefault()}

            break;
        }
     });        

})
</script>
```

the work to be done is still much.
This is just a simple example, I hope it can help you.